# Create a big image out of several other small images in MonoGame

Tags: monogame

How can I create one big Texture2D out of several other small Textures2Ds? Then display that image instead of all the small images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render different textures into one using `RenderTarget2D`

```
_renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_renderTarget);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque);
//draw some stuff.
SpriteBatch.End()

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Blue);
SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque);
SpriteBatch.Draw(_renderTarget, Vector2.Zero, Color.white);
SpriteBatch.End()
```